# 301 redirect that ignores URL parameters

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I figured out how to redirect my friends old blogger archives to his new WordPress archives with .htaccess like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

#Redirect to WP archive
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([0-9]{4})_([0-9]{2})_([0-9]{2})_archive.html$ /$1/$2/$3
```

However, if a person tries to access an old archive with the parameter m=1 (http://www.mydomain.com/2010_04_01_archive.html?m=1), it doesn't redirect! We want to ignore all possible parameters, and have it redirect just as above, to http://www.mydomain.com/2010/04/01/

Tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
RewriteEngine On

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule ^/([0-9]{4})_([0-9]{2})_([0-9]{2})_archive.html$ /$1/$2/$3 [R]
```

Thanks for your help!
Amanda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([0-9]{4})_([0-9]{2})_([0-9]{2})_archive\.html$ /$1/$2/$3? [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the first / and $.

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{4})_([0-9]{2})_([0-9]{2})_archive.html /$1/$2/$3 [R=301]
```

Comment: You need to remove the / in the beginning too. (I edited my answer)